# how to use polygon in snap.svg

Tags: html, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to create a polygon(triangle) in snap.svg. I read the docs and I'm still not sure what to  do. I see there's a polygon object in the docs, but there's no clear way in how to use it. Where would I put the points for my polygon?

Would it be something like this?

```
paper.polygon("M10, 20L30, 40");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use an array or just coords together, like

```
s.polygon(10,10,10,30,100,100).attr({ fill: "red", stroke: "blue" });
```

or

```
s.polygon([110,10,110,230,80,30]).attr({ fill: "yellow", stroke: "green" });
```